# Using C functions in *.a library from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c, pinvoke, wrapper

I have an API which is comprised of a header (.h) and the library (.a) files.

I've never touched C and i need to access this API from C# and interact with it's functions.

Most [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002240/calling-c-code-from-managed-code) regarding this topic say i need to do something like `[DllImport("insert_the_dll_name_here")]` this to invoke the DLL methods. But i only have the .h and .a files.

**What should i do?**

Should i compile these files into the DLL and then use pInvoke? If so, How?

Or should i write a wrapper class? If so how?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What OS?  `.a` files are usually compiled for Linux, while .NET is on Windows.

Comment: I use Windows. But i can also fire-up my virtualbox with linux if i have to. Are you saying i need to fire that up to compile the `.a` files?

Comment: If they're linux binaries (making calls to glibc), then you could link them inside a linux VM, but the resulting .so file wouldn't be any use on Windows (Windows DLLs can be used under Linux with the help of Wine, I know of no way to do the reverse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `.a` files contain Windows-format object files, then you can extract the archive (use the cygwin `ar` tool for that) and link those into a C++/CLI project.  C++/CLI can use your header files, call C functions directly, and create .NET classes which C# can use just as easily as any Microsoft-provided library class.

If your `.a` files contain Linux-format object files, you'll need to go back to whoever provided them and ask the code to be recompiled for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben (+1). How can i tell if the `.a` files contain Windows-format object files?

Comment: If the `objdump` program that comes with Visual C++ (or Windows SDK) gives reasonable output, they're Windows-format.  (The roughly equivalent Linux tool is `nm`, but I wouldn't bet against it understanding Windows format also).  I think you have to extract the objects first.